# VBA onclick event

Tags: vba, excel

```
<a href="#" onclick="show('11635356');">11635356</a>
```

The above HTML code shows the number 11635356 as a link on the web page. I want to click on this link. How to link to this page using Visual Basic for Excel?

Comment: Can you set id to some value for you to identify this element in the dom? i.e. `<a href="#" id="testMessage">Hello</a>`

Comment: it is an HTML code and i dont want to make any changes in it i just want to automate my web page. so i will not be able to set the ID to some value to identify the element so please any changes if possible in visual basic for excel i will be appreciating your efforts

Comment: Can you paste your html source at pastebin.com and share the link?

Comment: Hi shahkalpesh, I have done the same

Comment: Can you paste the link where I can see the source code?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
Set ancElem = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("a")
ancElem.Click
```

OR

```
Document.GetElementsByTagName("a").Item(0).FireEvent("click()")
```

[image]

Comment: @user2268910 change anc to ancElem.

Comment: I have tried all the things as follows 

Set ancElem = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("116516") ancElem.click

Set ancElem = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("a") 
ancElem.click


Set ancElem = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("a") 
116516.click

Comment: Set ancElem = IE.document.getelementsbytagname("a")
ancElem.Click where IE.document should be a valid object. Can you paste your entire code.

Comment: Try this Document.GetElementsByTagName("a").Item(0).FireEvent("click()")

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate ("http://home/url")
    Do
        If IE.ReadyState = 4 Then
            IE.Visible = True

Comment: task=pack.view.general&operacion=consultagen")
     Do
        If IE.ReadyState = 4 Then
            IE.Visible = True
            Exit Do
        Else
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop
    IE.Document.Forms(0).all("pk").Value = "11635356"
    IE.Document.Forms(0).submit
    Set ancElem = IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("11635356")
    ancElem.Click
   

End Sub

Comment: I have used this code in which it opens the web page opens the link, puts username and password and than search with the number 11635356 and after submitting this I am getting the link with 11635356 (So now I want to click on this link to go inside it I have tried by using url but the problem is that when I click on the link 11635356 than the same link is opening which was opened at the time of login http://home/url) sorry i am not able to use the proper link as i am getting error while post so consider that my link includes IP address as well i am sorry for this stupid way

Comment: Please change this  Set ancElem = IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("11635356")  to  Set ancElem = IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("a") and try. Let me know if its working.

Comment: IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a").Item(0).FireEvent ("click()") i have tried this but getting the Run time error '-2147024809 (80070057); Invalid argument

Comment: Now I have tried the same Set ancElem = IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("a") but getting the Run time Error '438' object does'nt support this property or method

Comment: Try this    Set ancElem = IE.Document.Forms(0).getelementsbytagname("a")
    ancElem.Click

Comment: Set ancElem = IE.Document.Forms(0).getelementsbytagname("a")
    ancElem.Click
   for this i got the same run time error as above i.e 438

Comment: Try this IE.Document.Forms(0).GetElementsByTagName("a").Item(0).FireEvent("click()")

Comment: if there are many anchor in your webpage you need to identify the index number of the anchor you want to click.
Set ancElem = IE.Document.Forms(0).getelementsbytagname("a")(0) ' 0 index number change the index number as per your requirement
ancElem.Click

Comment: IE.Document.Forms(0).GetElementsByTagName("a").Item(0).FireEvent("click()") I am getting the run time error '-2147024809 (8007) as invalid argument

Comment: Set ancElem = IE.Document.Forms(0).getelementsbytagname("a")(0)ancElem.Click when i am using this code small calender is getting opened

Comment: As said earlier you have to identify the index number of anchor tag which you want to click and refer in your code.

Comment: ok but how to find the anchor tag or anchor number in place of 0  as I am also searching the same in detail can you please guide me

Comment: To identify the index number you have to share your html code. Also there is a software IE inspector which helps to locate the element in HTML.

Comment: One more thing I was wanted to ask whether it is possible to press a TAB button using visual basic code on the web page because if It is possible than on 18th tab the required fill gets selected and than I will have to hit an ENTER button so it will do the same thing which I want

Comment: Instead of pressing the tab button see whats is the URL after pressing the tab button and then navigate to that URL accordingly in your code.

Comment: The URL for that link is same as that of URL at the time of login so thats why I failed to apply the logic you state above

Comment: If thats the case yes you can click the tab button programatically but for that have to see you html source code.

Comment: I am facing the issue to copy the whole HTML code so will try it again with some different ways but will it be possible for you to provide the syntax to press the TAB button and the ENTER button so that by thinking logically I will try and will let you know the status and I would like to thank you for dedicating yourself for my questions so thanks for it.

Comment: Honestly without looking at the html source code it would not be fair to write the code. I request you to paste the html socurce code in pastebin and provide us with a link.